# TabNavigator not switching tabs. navigation.navigate is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I just started a new project and added a TabNavigator.  when i tap on either of the tabs, i get a red error stating:

```
"navigation.navigate is not a function(In 'navigation/navigate(navigateion.state.routes[index].routeName', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)"
```

If I change the initial route, each tab will show correctly on screen, as well as highlight the correct tab on the bottom of the screen.

```js
export default TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Card: { screen: CardScreen },
    Schedule: { screen: ScheduleScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
```

Comment: Show the code which you used to move to next screen.

Comment: There is no code.  Just tapping on the tabs themselves should be handling that. https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/basic-tabs . basic tab setup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Downgrading React-navigation from 2.0.0 down to 1.0.3 solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I am using to change the **Tab**.

This is the defination of my customeTab

**`const customeTab = ({ navigation }) => {`**

Below is the code to naviagate:

```js
const routes = navigation.state.routes;
            {routes.map((route, index) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        activeOpacity={1.0}
                        onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate(route.key);
                        }
                        }
                        style={styles.tab}
                        key={route.key}
                    >
         // do you stuff to show title and image.
                    </TouchableOpacity>);
            })
            }
```

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/basic-tabs

this is the example in the docs.  theres no routes setup.  TabNavigator handles that.  I can run that example on my phone with no issues.

Comment: yet copying and pasting that code into my project yields the same `navigation.navigate is not a function` error...

Comment: well, if I downgrade to react-navigation 1.0.3, instead of the released 2.0, it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I thought the problem is in your navigation.

```js
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from "./Home"
import SettingsScreen from "./Settings"

export default TabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
});
```

If you want to shift one page to another page you have to use navigation method.

**Jumping between tabs**
Switching from one tab to another has a familiar API — *this.props.navigation.navigate.*

```js
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Settings"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Click this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation.html). This is a official doc that will help you.

Comment: Thanks for copying and pasting the documentation.  I had no clue that existed.  “Jumping between tabs” it to route to a new tab without peering on the tab itself.  The problem was with React-navigation 2.0.0.  Once I downgraded to 1.0.3, it worked as it should.